# Apex AST in JSON Blob

Tags: salesforce, apex, pmd

I am trying to work on a code formatter for Apex. I need the AST to plug it into a popular Javascript formatter (prettier). Is there by any chance I can get the Apex AST and put it in JSON blob format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess would be to use apex-jorje ([see this to learn how to use the jars from Maven](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/tree/master/pmd-apex/repo)) to parse the code into a Java AST, and then transverse the tree to convert each node to JS in whichever way you find fitting.

Parsing the code is straight-forward enough ([see an example here](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-apex/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/apex/ast/ApexParser.java#L43-L46)), and once you have a `Compilation`, you can transverse the AST.

Since this is not really a PMD issue, you can use the AST provided by Jorje, you don't need the adaptation to PMD's AST structures.

Comment: Thanks @Johnco! Any chance to ask follow up questions. I am not familiar with the Java world much. I need to install the repo local and then use the code provided in the example to somehow parse it?

Comment: If the only reason for doing this in JS is that's the language you are comfortable with, I'd suggest you write your own parser in JS... Otherwise you are having 2 problems instead of one. The alternative would be to learn Java and do the formatter directly on Java taking advantage of the oficial Jorje parser.